# Working with Virtualbox and Vagrant offline

Tags: macos, networking, virtualbox, vagrant

I can entirely accept that this question is terrible.. However, I'm looking for advice on where to even start.

I'm using Vagrant and Virtualbox through the help of puphpet.com on a Macbook air.  As long as my wireless adapter is on, and it has a connection to something, everything works fine.

However - if I'm traveling, let's say, and I'm on an airplane.. I can't seem to access the remote host outside of vagrant ssh'ing into it.

I see the vboxnet0 adapter.. but it's like without my mac having a network of its own, I can't ping the box or access it's web resources (with hardwired hostnames to ips) ..

What am I missing?  How can I use Vagrant/Virtualbox without any internet connectivity.. More specifically, I'd like to access the sites I have setup on Vagrant/Virtualbox through my macbook air.

That make any sense?  Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make sense in my ears. Where is the VBox machine - on your macbook? About what "remote host" are you talking?

Comment: Yes - on my macbook.  Remote host = guest OS (in my case, a ubunutu instance).  If I try and hit http://10.10.10.10 (IP for guest host nginx) without SOME kind of network connection on my macbook, it won't work.  I can, however, 'vagrant ssh' into the instance so I know its up.

Comment: Have you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with the hosts file on your macbook. If you go into your Vagrantfile, there should be a line with something like `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.101"`. Add this address to your `/etc/hosts` file with the hostname you want for the box, and you should be up and running.
Alternatively, you could use the ip address assigned to your box directly as long as you are using the correct address. If you are using a puphpet manifest, it will most likely be set to `192.168.56.101` like above.